# Trim All columns in a temp table and Select data

Tags: sql, trim, temp-tables

Got a quick question.

I first select a dataset INTO a **temp table**.

The data contained in the columns of the temp table, contains extra spaces in them. Many columns exist with extra spaces. So, I googled to check how to remove all spaces in the columns.

Found this solution [SQL Server: How to perform Rtrim on all varchar columns of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552154/sql-server-how-to-trim-all-columns-in-a-table)

But, I tried to implement the same for the temp table, but it does not work as it is, as the temp tables are created in a different schema.

So, I modified the same and tried. But no luck.
Can someone point me, where I am doing it wrong?

The code is as follows:

```
DECLARE @Op NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @table_name AS VARCHAR(300) 

SET @table_name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE name LIKE '#tempFinalResults%')

SET @Op = ' UPDATE ' + @table_name + ' SET COLUMN_NAME = LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN_NAME)) FROM tempDB.information_Schema.Columns WHERE DATA_Type IN (''varchar'', ''char'', ''nchar'', ''nvarchar'')'

Exec sp_executesql @Op

Select * from #tempFinalResults
```

Thanks guys. Appreciate it.

thanks,
Shawn

Comment: You need `SELECT c.name FROM tempdb.sys.columns c WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..#tempFinalResults')`

Comment: What's the point of inserting the data, and *THEN* trimming it.  Why not trim it on the insert?  `INSERT INTO #temp SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(field1)), LTRIM(RTRIM(field2))...`

Answer (score 2):

If you know which columns need to be trimmed, you could trim them as part of your select into the temp table, as in

```
SELECT 
ID,
RTRIM(myCharColumn1) as myColumn1,
RTRIM(myCharColumn2) as myColumn2,
RTRIM(myCharColumn3) as myColumn3
INTO #myTempTable
WHERE.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have to build the list of column names with a `SELECT` statement so that it loops through all columns.

I think this might work:

```
DECLARE @Op NVARCHAR(3000)
DECLARE @table_name AS VARCHAR(300) 

SET @table_name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE name LIKE '#tempFinalResults%')

SELECT @Op = COALESCE(@Op + ',[', '[') + COLUMN_NAME +
    '] = LTRIM(RTRIM([' + COLUMN_NAME + ']))' 
FROM 
    tempDB.information_Schema.Columns 
WHERE 
    DATA_Type IN ('varchar', 'char', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')

SET @Op = 'UPDATE [' + @table_name + '] SET ' + @Op

Exec sp_executesql @Op
```