# How to apply a function to all fields (all columns of all rows)

Tags: sql-server

i have a table that contains only varchar columns. Each field has the same pattern '"xxxxx"' and I would like to clean / trim the leading and trailing " from every single field .

I know how to do it for a single column but I would like to do it for all columns in a dynamic manner (with a dynamic set of the column name)

Thanks

Comment: Use sys.columns to generate your sql for you.

Comment: @SeanLange: could you give me a working example as I am beginning SQL dev

Comment: Do you want to trim the column names only or data as well?

Comment: @Pinwar13: I want to trim the data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove leading and trailing quotes in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066134/how-can-i-remove-leading-and-trailing-quotes-in-sql-server)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: I have seen this question but my difficulty was more related to clean all columns than how to clean a specific one. But true that question may complement mine

Comment: Possible to combine with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552154/sql-server-how-to-perform-rtrim-on-all-varchar-columns-of-a-table perhaps?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: yes absolutely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can do this. It is going to require some dynamic sql no matter you slice this because you have to dynamically get the column names.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

select @SQL = 'Update YourTable set ' + STUFF((select ', replace(' + QUOTENAME(c2.name) + ', ''"'', '''')'
    from sys.columns c2
    where object_id = object_id('YourTable')
    order by c2.column_id
    for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')    
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('YourTable')
group by object_id

select @SQL
--exec sp_executesql @SQL --You can uncomment this when you comfortable with the output
```

Comment: looks interesting but when i try to run it it fails with the following error :


Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: it happens when i uncomment the last line

Comment: So did you get it figured out or is there still a problem?